# How to ignore already compressed files and remove original raw file

Tags: batch-file, compression, 7zip

I have tried the following code with 7zip but once I run the batch script it keeps compressing the already compressed file inside the folder. Is there a way to ignore .zip file type and delete the original file after it has been compressed? Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Code:

```
FOR %%i IN ("C:\filepath....\*HAEC040.D*") DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a  -mx "%%~i.zip" "%%i"
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6ZcB.png)

Comment: Perhaps `) DO IF /I NOT "%%~xi"==".zip" "C:\P…`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment, *(plus a suggested deletion command)*:

```bat
For %%A In ("C:\filepath....\*HAEC040.D*") Do If /I Not "%%~xA"==".zip" ("%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx "%%~A.zip" "%%A" && Del /A /F "%%A")
```